# USB Barcode reader in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to read a barcode from a USB scanner.

I am getting code like  `héà&"à')&'_h` or `qà&é"'(èq` when using SerialPort connection.

Is there a way to decode this value?

```
        private void Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
```

/*

*/

```
        private void btnStart_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
                    _serialPort.Open();

                _serialPort.Write("SI\r\n");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
            }
        }

        void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            String data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new Object[] { data });
        }

        private void si_DataReceived(String data)
        {
            textBox1.Text = data.Trim().ToString();
        }
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tested what your USB scanner does when you open up Notepad and scan something? If you're using a recent scanner, it already returns the value read as a string: if you scan a barcode which says '00000', '00000' gets inserted in Notepad. If so, you don't have to put this much effort in reading the input.

Comment: Check the port settings. Try a few different baud rates. The ASCII that you receive should be human readable

Comment: If it's not human readable, and u have the right port settings, u might still be able to figure out the encoding. Try treating the bytes as unsigned 16bit integers or something common to your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I finally found out way my barcode scanner was giving me such weired codes. in fact, everything work well when I turn on my Lock caps. It work well also with Notepad.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Member of the SerialPort-Class.

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
_serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
// Encoding
_serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

_serialPort.Open();
```